# Qtip2 slow in IE8

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I use qtip2 to display messagebox above my images by this way:

```
$('#july').qtip({
   content: {text: $('div#messages_box div.message_july')}, 
   show: {event: 'click', delay: 0},
   hide: {event: 'unfocus'},
   position: {my: 'left center', at: 'right center', target: '#july'},
   style: {classes: 'ui-tooltip-rounded ui-tooltip-mine ui-tooltip-shadow', width: '350px', tip: {width: 20, height: 15}}
});
```

In Firefox, IE7, IE9 it works fine but IE8 I have to wait about 5-6sec to display it after the click.

Does anyone have a solution to this ?

Thanks

Comment: IE is really slow in general. Read this. http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/benchmarks/sunspider/default.html

Comment: but 5-6 secs?  I use qtip2 in my site and the difference may be 0.2 seconds (if that).  Is the page in question huge?

Comment: The page is bigg yeah, cause is a kind of parallax style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: in the jQuery element, just add .html(). By this way, we get all the node content as the message and lost the node but it become really faster to show.

```
$('#july').qtip({
   content: {text: $('div#messages_box div.message_july').html()}, 
   show: {event: 'click', delay: 0},
   hide: {event: 'unfocus'},
   position: {my: 'left center', at: 'right center', target: '#july'},
   style: {classes: 'ui-tooltip-rounded ui-tooltip-mine ui-tooltip-shadow', width: '350px', tip: {width: 20, height: 15}}
});
```

Thanks